# Google Cloud Spanner migration

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Is there any tools available for Oracle to Google Cloud Spanner migration?
Also whether Spanner supports Stored Procedure, Views, Triggers, Function, etc ?

Comment: Is this a live migration (i.e., no downtime is a requirement) OR can you take downtime for the migration?

Answer (score 2):

Cloud spanner does not yet support Stored Producer, Views, or Triggers.

Answer (score 1):

We are following this approach: Extract a csv for each table from Oracle database. We will place them in a bucket and run a dataflow job that will convert csv to avro and import them together into SPANNER maintaining the relationship
Key points: You have to create schema in Spanner beforehand, try to have columns names and datatypes as close as possible to avoid too much work within Dataflow job.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Spanner currently does not support these features. For migration, once the data can be read by Cloud Dataflow, the Cloud Spanner Dataflow connector can be used to import the data into Cloud Spanner.

Answer (score 0):

I think we should look for other approaches
For migration, once data can be read by Cloud Dataflow, the Cloud Spanner Dataflow connector can be used to import data to Cloud Spanner.
Also, read this [article](https://alpacked.io/blog/why-is-cloud-migration-important-for-business), it can help you understand Google Cloud Spanner migration

Comment: Please add relevant sections of the answer here itself as links might change over time.